# Match substrings separated by a word with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a sentence like this: **"AOrbOrCOrDOreOrdOr..."** . I'm trying to match all the word like "**A**", "**b**", "**C**" and so on. But, it just returns "**A**", "**bOr**", "**cOr**",... Here is my pattern: `/(.*?(?:(?=Or))|(?<!Or).*?)/`.
I'm very new to Regular Expression.

Comment: Are you sure that you want/can solve this using regular expressions?

Comment: I 'm learning RegEx so I want to try to solve this with RegEx if possible.

Comment: The quality/robustness of a regular expression depends on having a good understanding of the variability of the input text.  With only one sample string (and a contrived one at that), this question is a little too Unclear to confidently give a professional answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a lookahead in your regex to match all the alphabets which are followed by the string `Or`,

```
[A-Za-z](?=Or)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/14)

If you want to match any character followed by the string `Or`, then you could use `.` instead of `[A-Za-z]`.

```
.(?=Or)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/13)

Comment: Thank you. But with a sentence like this: "ABOrCOrDdOrE" , it just returns "B", "C", "d" and not "e". I try to change the pattern to "[A-Za-z]*(?=Or)" and it just returns "ABOrCOrDd". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much! What I expected is "AB", "C", "Dd", "E". And your pattern works great with a little changes. Here is the pattern that I changed: `((?<=Or|^)[A-Za-z]+?(?:(?=Or)|\b))` .

Comment: I you want to match the last E also then use this http://regex101.com/r/sX9fR0/16 , it's even simpler than your regex.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to using a regex would be to use `explode()`:

```
$string = 'AOrbOrCOrDOreOrdOr...';
$words = explode('Or', $string);
```

Note that if you are having a constant delimiter, like `Or`, you can use `explode()` which is faster than using a regex.

Comment: **This.** No need for a regex here -- the other solution (with regular expressions) is actually inferior to this one both in terms of readability and performance.

Answer (score -1):

you can use explode function:

```
$text  = "AOrbOrCOrDOreOrdOr...";
$array = explode('Or', $text);
```

and then you have now an array with the parts:

```
array("A", "b", "C", "D", "e",) // ...and so on
```

Comment: What is the loop utility?